# fusion news or cutenews

Tags: php, wordpress, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I am looking at  using cutenews or fusionnews, neither have the specific option i want which is when a new article is posted to email all my subscribers the last article.

I would like to know which one is most customizable to do this or of another application that can do this? i didnt want to use wordpress because i want to custime the layout and page, but if thats the only option then i may stick to wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

And you can't customize the layout and page in Wordpress because?

You could use a mail-list for the mail. Google Groups has some limitations to prevent spam, but it's worth the trouble. If your server has mailman, it may have less restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find a plugin to do this. Or you can create one your self where if you have a database of emails then you can create a function in your theme funtions that after you post emails all your emails in the database.

I am thinking of making a plugin that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you are choosing between those two options? The only "advantage" of those older systems is that they use flat-file storage and do not require MySQL. However, this is pretty much a weakness for many reasons including performance and security.

Those types of scripts - Cutenews in particular - are remnants from a bygone era when many hosts supported PHP but not MySQL. This is no longer true and nearly all cheap PHP hosting includes MySQL too.

By the way, Cutenews 1.3.x is full of security holes. Cutenews 1.4 is better but is many years old now and no longer developed so could easy have problems. So of the two options, Fusion News would be the *lesser of two evils*. However, I would strongly recommend using a more modern platform such as Wordpress.